# Error Handling with Sitecore Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, sitecore

I've recently implemented exception handling code into my existing sublayouts. It works, however, the only information I get is the method throwing the exception and the class it belongs to. Many times, I'm getting NullReferenceException errors due to unpublished items or fields of items. Is there a simple way to include the item id in the thrown exception in order to identify the culprit?

Thanks in advance, 
Shaun

Comment: what do you mean with item id in throw exception? Do you mean current item id or something else?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the situations you're getting these exceptions? Are you trying to access items in a multilist or something of that nature?

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting a `NullReferenceException` because an item is missing or unpublished, that means Sitecore is not able to resolve the item, so there usually won't be an ID to mention in the Exception message.

What you could do is try to log some information about the current request, mainly the request URL and the referring URL.
In that way you have some means of figuring out what caused the exception to be thrown.

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request` to get current request object (check for Null on `HttpContext.Current` first though).
Then use `Request.Url` and `Request.UrlReferer` to get info on the request URL's.